# Unable to comment in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, comments

As the title states, my collaborator is unable to comment on a Colab notebook that I shared with him. He is listed as an editor in the permissions. His notebook looks like this in the upper-right corner:

[image]

And mine looks like this:

[image]

He's also unable to do it with CTRL+ALT+M.

He's running Chrome and can comment in other notebooks. Any ideas what might be happening?